# Ensure that a Sinatra hash always has a valid value

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to ensure that a Sinatra hash always has a valid value.

Is there a more-concise way to write this?

```
params[:v] = if [:icons,:list].include? (params[:v] ||= :list).downcase.to_sym then (params[:v] ||= :list).downcase.to_sym else :list end
```

Comment: I'm really unsure what your goal is here. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I'd write this in multiple lines, so that you don't have to write out the complex conversion multiple times:

```
v = (params[:v] || :list).downcase.to_sym
params[:v] = if %i[icons list].include?(v) then v else :list end
```